# Return local changes after SVN revert

Tags: svn

I made `update` on my project and after updating some files were in conflict state. On files makred as conflicted I choosed `revert` command. So I lost all local modifications. It's possible to return my last modifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`svn revert` reverts all modifications, so they are lost.

If you have a backup, the files still open in your editor or use some 'undelete tool', you still might get them back.

Answer (score 2):

From the [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.revert.html):

> svn revert is inherently dangerous, since its entire purpose is to throw away data—namely, your uncommitted changes. Once you've reverted, Subversion provides no way to get back those uncommitted changes.

It would seem, that unless you have those changes backed up somewhere using another method, you won't be able to restore them.